# Nexus repository manager 2.0 as PyPI Repositories

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, repository, nexus

We have Nexus repository manager 2.0, I was trying set up a PyPl Repositories, the only thing I can found is for 3.0 (https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories). I give it shot using the instruction there, but gave me error messages:

```
KeyError: Missing 'nexus' section from the configuration file
or not a complete URL in --repository.
Maybe you have a out-dated '~/.pypirc' format?
more info: https://docs.python.org/distutils/packageindex.html#pypirc
```

Here is how my .pypirc looks like:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    nexus

[nexus]
repository = some_url
username = "{{ NEXUS_USER }}"
password = "{{ NEXUS_PASS }}"
```

Here is my upload call in .travis:

```
twine upload -r nexus *
```

I double checked and the username and password are correct, when I try to upload files, it throw gave error messages as shown above. I am not sure it is related to version or some incorrect format here, any clue here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPI repos are only supported in Nexus Repo 3.0, sorry for the confusion. On a side note, why did you think they were supported in 2? I'll see if I can get that clearer.

Comment: Thanks @DarthHater for you response, we currently only supported 2 so I just try to figure out if there is any way to get PyPl there or any other recommendations are welcome!

Comment: No currently supported ways. You could in theory craft your own implementation for Nexus Repo 2 but I think it would be better to just figure out when you can upgrade to Nexus Repo 3.

Comment: This page lists "PyPI Repositories" under Repository 2 Feature: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-manager-2-to-3-feature-equivalency